# Parse multiple xml files in a folder

Tags: python, xml, csv

I'm new and learning Python. I'm working on XML files (5,754 files)in a folder. Working with os module I can print all the files names without a problem. I can parse one file and write to a CSV file without a problem. I'm having a problem trying to parse all the files in the folder. Please help and thank you. code snippets and all code below.

This works fine and prints all 5,754 file names

```
import os
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:\Users\dan\Desktop\parse"):
    for f in files:
        clinical = os.path.join(path, f)
        print(clinical)
```

OUTPUT:
C:\Users\dan\Desktop\toparse\ABC0000xxxx\ ABC 00009932.xml
C:\Users\dan\Desktop\toparse\ ABC 0000xxxx\ ABC 00009945.xml
C:\Users\dan\Desktop\toparse\ ABC 0000xxxx\ ABC 00009958.xml

Working code parse: write to CSV

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

tree = ET.parse("ABC00000102.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    for child in root.iter():
        key = child.tag
        value = child.text
        writer.writerow([key, value])
```

my code for the folder prints all files but errors below
code

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:\Users\dan\Desktop\parse"):
    for f in files:
        clinical = os.path.join(path, f)
        print(clinical)

tree = ET.parse("clinical")
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root.iter():
    key = child.tag
    value = child.text
    writer.writerow([key, value])
```

errors
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dan/PycharmProjects/clinicals/example.py", line 14, in 
    tree = ET.parse("clinical")
  File "C:\Users\dan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1197, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Users\dan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 587, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'clinical'
Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: What do/don’t you understand from that error message? I find it quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `ET.parse("clinical")`, which looks for a file named "clinical" in the directory you're currently working in.

If you want it to open the path specificied by the `clinical` variable instead, you'll need to do `ET.parse(clinical)` instead.

Also, if your intention is to parse every file found, you'll need to fix your indentation to make sure it happens in the for-loop. Currently, your code will only ever parse the last file it finds in the directory, because your parsing happens after the loop.

Comment: Thank you much. This helped me out, Bless.

Comment: You're welcome! Also, if you're new to the site, make sure to answers as "accepted" if they solve your problem